# VBA Input data dynamic

Tags: vba

I've a problem with my code in VBA.
I'll try to explain better:

In my workbook I've 3 different sheets :A1,A2,A3
-through InputBox, I scan A1 and go to sheet A1, then I start to scan different numbers: 1234567890,0987654321 and i shoud write them in column B,but the inputbox does not reopen automatically.

If I scan again example A2, then the VBA open sheet A2 and then go to column B and then I start to scan different numbers: 1234567890,0987654321 etc.

here my code

---

```
Function WorksheetExists(WSName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    WorksheetExists = Worksheets(WSName).Name = WSName
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub input_()

    Dim SHNAME As String
    Do Until WorksheetExists(SHNAME)
        SHNAME = inputbox("Enter", "Location or Job")
        If Not WorksheetExists(SHNAME) Then MsgBox SHNAME & " Doesn't Exist!", vbExclamation
    Exit Do
    Loop
    If WorksheetExists(SHNAME) Then Sheets(SHNAME).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Why should an inputbox open automatically? It should only open when your code tells it to open. Based on your description, it isn't quite clear when you want that to be and how that differs from your current code. How are you calling `input()`?

Comment: I need to open inputbox automaticaly because it works like a data entry

Comment: How are you currently calling `input()`? If you want `input()` to be called automatically, invoke it in an event handler like `WorkSheet_Activate` or `WorkSheet_Change()`. But -- the entire point of `input()` seems to be to go to another sheet, so having this run automatically the instant you get to a new sheet would prevent you from doing anything in that sheet. It really isn't clear what you want to happen.

Comment: the worksheets I can add manually and with different names, but when I type in the input box A1 - opens the sheet A1 and with the InputBox open I write in the column B different numbers composed of 10 digits..can I send you an example file?

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow doesn't work that way. A question should be self-contained. InputBoxes can't remain open while a sheet is being edited. If you want that type of behavior, you need a non-modal userform rather than a simple inputbox.

Comment: i understand . i'll try in this way with a userform. thank you